# translate function and unicode conversion

Tags: python, unicode

I am trying to remove punctuation from the text below. I am converting the text to unicode to avoid any encoding issues later on that might come up.

```
import string
st = "I absolutely go incredibly far. Zach went fast over crab sand land.\n\nThis is a new paragraph. This is the second sentence in that paragraph. This exsquisite utterance is indubitably the third sentence of this fine text.\n\nPlagiarism detection can be operationalized by decomposing a document into natural sections, such as sentences, chapters, or topically related blocks, and analyzing the variance of stylometric features for these sections. In this regard the decision problems in Sect. 1.2 are of decreasing complexity: instances of AVFIND are comprised of both a selection problem (finding suspicious sections) and an AVOUTLIER problem; instances of AVBATCH are a restricted variant of AVOUTLIER since one has the additional knowledge that all elements of a batch are (or are not) outliers at the same time."
st = unicode(st, errors = 'ignore')
for word in st.split(' '):
    wd = word.lower().translate(string.maketrans("",""), string.punctuation)
    print wd
```

However, the translate function inexplicably raises an error about number of arguments.

```
TypeError: translate() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

Removing the unicode conversion step ensures correct execution, but it is imperative and so is the translate function. How can I achieve my goal without any errors and keep both functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str.translate()` and `unicode.translate()` take different arguments. This violates [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), but is required given the large number of characters available in Unicode strings.

```
word.lower().translate(dict((x, None) for x in string.punctuation))
```

Answer (score 2):

That will be because you are calling `unicode.translate()`, not `str.translate()`.

```
>>> help(unicode.translate)
translate(...)
    S.translate(table) -> unicode

    Return a copy of the string S, where all characters have been mapped
    through the given translation table, which must be a mapping of
    Unicode ordinals to Unicode ordinals, Unicode strings or None.
    Unmapped characters are left untouched. Characters mapped to None
    are deleted.
```

This should work the same, i.e. remove punctuation characters:

```
wd = word.lower().translate({ord(c): None for c in string.punctuation})
```

By the way, for `str` objects, you can simply do this:

```
wd = word.lower().translate(None, string.punctuation)
```

i.e. when `None` is specified for the translation table the characters in the second argument are removed.